# Using JavaScript top.init within iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an application, AppA, where we use Javascript function using top.init() in most of the places. Now I have to use this application as part of a different application, say AppB.
I have used an iFrame to call AppA inside AppB.

The issue is the Javascript inside AppA. When it calls top.initXXX(), it is trying to search for the function at main window's top level and it is failing. I want to access the top.initXXX() method at iFrame level.

Is there a simple configuration to do this job ?

Comment: Yes, reference the JavaScript source within the iframe.

Comment: can you give some example ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Show us your code.

Comment: Unless you specifically want to cross frames, you should never use `top`.

Comment: i Know.. But that was the legacy application that I can make much changes now..

Answer (score 0):

`top` always accesses top-level page. If your situation is "iframe within iframe" you should use `parent` notation.

E.g. if AppA is inside of AppB, to call function of AppB from inside of AppA use

`parent.initXXX()` instead of `top.initXXX()`